# Is certificate Subject the content of certificate?

Tags: pki

Is certificate Subject the content of certificate?

such as:

Subject DN = Subject Distinguished Name = the unique identifier for what this thing is. Includes information about the thing being certified, including common name, organization, organization unit, country codes, etc.

Subject Key = part (or all) of the certificate's private/public key pair. If it's coming from the certificate, it's the public key. If it's coming from a key store in a secure location, it's probably the private key. Either part of the key is the cryptographic data used by the thing that received the certificate.

Subject certificate - the end point for the transaction - this is the thing requesting some secure capability - like integrity checking, authentication, privacy, etc.

And what content of Subject is used for IKE V2?

Answer (score 4):

A certificate binds an *identity* to a *public key*.  The binding is performed by the issuing authority (VeriSign, Cybertrust, etc.) digitally signing the contents of the certificate.

The Subject of a certificate indicates the entity for which the certificate was generated.  If it's an SSL certificate, it may correspond to a server and include the server's DNS name, for example.  If it's an e-mail digital signature certificate it may correspond to a person's e-mail address.  You are correct that it includes the organizational unit, etc.

The Subject Key is the public key in the equation.  While there is a private key corresponding to the certificate, the certificate itself only contains the public key.

Comment: That's right. So the "content" of the certificate is the binding of the key (and its usage flags, etc) to the subject identity.